# Homotopy equivalence?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Can someone explaine what this means mathematicaly :

"Let us denote by $h: X\rightarrow Y$ a homotopic equivalence map for which $h|_{Y}$ is the identity "

- Remark: $Y$ is include in $X$

Please

Thank you.

Comment: Try not to repeat punctuation in your title. Putting extra question marks doesn't further compel anyone to answer your question and, in fact, may cause some to turn away from the post. As for the question itself.. it doesn't make a lot of sense to me since $h$ is defined on $X$, not $Y$. The only way I can see this making sense is if you have that $Y$ is a subspace of $X$.

Comment: I thought I had answered this sufficiently in the chatroom, but seeing as you have reposted the same question, it seems there was something lacking in my explanation or some language barrier (as evidenced by the multiple spelling errors in your post).  If there is a specific part that is causing difficulty in your understanding, please specify what exactly it is you don't understand.  Otherwise, all answers you will receive will be given in a very similar level of detail as what I already attempted to give.

Comment: i don't understand the relation with retraction

Answer (score 3):

This makes sense when $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ (otherwise we cannot restrict $X$ to $Y$). Then it just means that $h: X \to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence satisfying $h(y)=y$ for all $y \in Y$.

A [homotopy equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Homotopy_equivalence) is a map which admits an inverse up to homotopy.

Comment: so there is  a contious map $g: Y\subset X$ such that $h\circ g=id_Y$ and $g\circ h=id_X$ with $h(y)=y, \forall y\in Y$ ?

Comment: No; there is a continuous map $g: Y \to X$ such that $h \circ g \simeq id_Y$ (as maps $Y \to Y$) and $g \circ h \simeq id_X$ (as maps $X \to X$). So $g$ and $h$ are not actual inverses, but inverses up to homotopy.